# How do I get F# Forge to work

Tags: f#, ionide

I can't seem to get Forge to work.

I'm using VS Code 1.6.1 with Ionide-F# 2.8.2. Until now I've only compiled scripts, but I need a project file for a specfic .dll to work (Unmanaged Exports).

However I can't seem to get an F# project going with Forge. When I use the `>F# New Project" command it tells me I need to refresh my templates, because I don't have any.

If I refresh, nothing happens. I have git installed as was suggested in other places, but to no avail.

When I open Forge.exe directly from my C:\Users\>USER<\.vscode\bin-forge directory, it doesn't even go into interactive mode. I downloaded Forge separately with the same result.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: I assume `git` is on the path? What happens if you download [forge.zip](https://github.com/fsharp-editing/Forge/releases) unpack it and doubleclick on `forge.cmd` or `Forge.exe` inside the `bin` folder?

Comment: git is on the path and works with my proxy. As stated above I downloaded forge.zip and executed Forge.exe directly. It doesn't go into interactive mode there either.

Comment: just a vague guess, are  there any security restrictions on the account? Maybe try it executing with admin rights. Something could be blocking a security dialog to allow it if nothing is happening in that case. Nothing happens even if you execute from the cmd/bash/ps prompt?

Comment: I executed from cmd with admin privileges, and directly with admin privileges now. Didn't change the behavior. Thank you though.

Comment: You could check with the Forge guys on gitter or slack.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why it's working now, the only thing I can remember doing is adding the following to my user settings:

```
"FSharp.toolsDirPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/F#/4.0/Framework/v4.0",
"FSharp.fsiFilePath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/F#/4.0/Framework/v4.0/Fsi.exe"
```

Maybe Forge didn't find the F# tools, but they're on the windows path, so I can't fathom why it helped.